# Writing a square root function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a square root function in R. The function is supposed to behave like sqrt() but not use that function of course. I'm supposed to use Newton's method for computing the square root, which is:

y(a+1) = [y(a) + x / y(a)]/2

Here x is the number I'm trying to calculate the square root of and y(0) would be the initial guess of the square root of x.

The function is supposed to take in four arguments: x (the number I'm trying to compute the square root of), eps (the difference in value between iterations that are considered be equal), iter (the max number of iterations), and verbose (says I want to output intermediate results).

My issue is that I am not very well versed in writing functions in R. I have experience in C++, but they are slightly different in R.

I believe I'm supposed to write something that goes like this.

Asks the user to input a number as a guess for the value we want to calculate the square root of. Make a for loop from 1 to iter with two if statements 1) that stop the function and output the y value if the max number of iterations have been reached 2) stop the function and output the y value if the difference between successive iterations is less than eps.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
MySqrt <- function (x, eps = 1e-6, iter = 100, verbose = TRUE) {
 for (i in 0:itmax) {
   y[0] <- readline(prompt="Please enter your initial square root      guess: ")
   y[i + 1] = (y[i] + x / y[i])/2
   if (i == 100) {
     stop (return(y[i + 1]))
   }
   if (abs(y[i + 1] - y[i]) < eps) {
     stop (return(y[i + 1]))
   }
}
return(y[i + 1])
}
```

Here is the error I receive after entering the initial square root guess: Error in y[0] <- readline(prompt = "Please enter your initial square root guess: ") : 
  object 'y' not found

Honestly, I didn't expect the code to work because I'm sure there are more than one errors.

Comment: Firstly, R doesn't use 0-indexing, so `y[0]` is a problem - `y[1]` is the first part of a vector. Secondly, `y` doesn't exist before you try to assign to a sub-section of it, hence the "object 'y' not found" error.

Comment: `stop` is used for (deliberately) raising an error, so you probably don't want to use that here. `return` is for ending execution early; otherwise the last line of the expression will be returned.

Comment: @thelatemail So should the first line of the function definition create y as an empty vector i.e. y <- vector(mode="numeric",length=0)?

Comment: @Steve - that is one solution, yes.

Comment: "Asks the user to input a number" -- why? If the user wants to use your function, they will use it in the console. No need to pester them. Write a pure function.

Comment: @thelatemail okay but now the issue is x is an integer and y is a vector so the error I'm receiving is "Error in x/y[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: `if (i == 100)` is problematic since it hard-wires in the default value of `iter`, ignoring anything that the user might input instead.

Comment: @JohnColeman So are you saying I should just give y[1] a value in the function definition? i.e. a random number like 10

Comment: @JohnColeman oh I see what you mean about the if (i == 100). So I'm thinking that instead saying if (i==iter+100) would work instead correct?

Comment: `x/2` is a reasonable default starting value. Newton's method converges rapidly. If you want, you could make the choice for the user, or you could make it another input variable. Whatever you do, once the function is invoked, it should already have everything it needs to compute with no further user-input required.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on square root approximation discusses initial seed values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots , but if the goal is to gain experience writing an R function, it might not be worth your effort to optimize that step.

Comment: Just use `if(i == iter)` since `iter` will be either 100 or the user-supplied iteration limit.

Comment: @JohnColeman interesting wikipedia article, but yeah i think that step really isn't important as I'm just trying to get experience writing R functions. Also changed it to if (i == iter)...But I'm still not sure how to solve the issue of the input x being divided by y[i]. I get an error message that says "Error in x/y[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator". I assume that's because x is a numeric and y is a vector, but that doesn't make sense to me. If you were to create a vector called a (say that a<-c(1,2)) and then do 2/a, you'd have no problem, the output would be 2 1.

Answer (score 1):

You should use iter instead of itmax. 
I initialized y within the function and input of y should be formatted as a number instead of a character. You could also simplify the if statement by using | (or). 
I also added "cat" function so you could see what i is before the function prints out the square root value.

```
MySqrt <- function (x, eps = 1e-6, iter = 100, verbose = TRUE) {
  y = 0
  y[1] = as.numeric(readline(prompt="Please enter your initial square root      guess: "))
  for (i in 1:iter) {
    y[i+1] = as.numeric((y[i] + (x/y[i]))/2)
    if (i == 100 || abs(y[i+1] - y[i]) < eps) {
      cat("This is", i,"th try: \n")
      return(y[i+1])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simply:

```
newton.raphson <- function(x, start, epsilon=0.0001, maxiter=100) {
  y <- c(start) # initial guess
  a <- 1        # number of iterations
  while (TRUE) {
    y <- c(y, (y[a] + x / y[a])/2)
    if (abs(y[a+1] - y[a]) < epsilon | a > maxiter) { # converged or exceeded maxiter
      return(y[a+1])
    }
    a <- a + 1
  }
}

newton.raphson(2, 0.5, 0.01)
# [1] 1.414234

newton.raphson(3, 0.5, 0.01)
# [1] 1.732051
```

Answer (score 0):

since sqrt(n) < n/2 then with precision of 1/10000

```
sqrnt=function(y){
    x=y/2 
    while (abs(x*x-y) > 1e-10) 
    {x=(x+y/x)/2 }
    x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Newton’s method. If you want to know the square root of `a`, you can start estimate a number, `x` (for examples `a/2`), you can compute a better estimate with the following formula:

```
y = (x + a / x) / 2
```

If `y != x`, you set `x = y`, and repeat until `y == x`. Then you get the square root of `a`. Please see the code below:

```
square_root <- function(a) {
  x <- a/2
  while (TRUE) {
    y <- (x + a / x) / 2
    if (y == x) break
    x <- y
  } 
  return(y)
}
```